# Let $a = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $a = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}$.
Find the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.
Notice that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{ b_0 + b_1 \sqrt{2} ~|~ b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.
Also, $\mathbb{Q}(a) = \{ c_0 + c_1 a + c_2 a^2 + c_3 a^3 ~|~ c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$
Since, $a = \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} \implies a^2 + (\sqrt{2} - 2) = 0$.
Notice that $x^2 + (\sqrt{2} - 2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $a^2 + (\sqrt{2} - 2) = 0$ and $x^2 + (\sqrt{2} - 2)$ is monic polynomial.
So, the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is $x^2 + (\sqrt{2} - 2)$.

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$:
Notice that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) = \{ b_0 + b_1\sqrt{2} ~|~ b_0,b_1 \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(a) = \{ c_0 + c_1 a + c_2 a^2 + c_3 a^3 ~|~ c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{Q} \}$.
Since, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(a)$ [which I don't know how to prove this is true].
Then, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ can be prove by using the Subfield Test.
Let $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $y \neq 0$.
Then, $x = a + b\sqrt{2}$ and $y = c + d\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$.
Since, $x - y = (a + b\sqrt{2}) - (c + d\sqrt{2}) = (a-c) + (b-d)\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.
Also, $xy^{-1} = (a + b\sqrt{2})(c + d\sqrt{2})^{-1} = \frac{ac-2bd}{c^2 - 2d^2} + \frac{bc-ad}{c^2-2d^2}\sqrt{2}$.
Since, $\frac{ac-2bd}{c^2 - 2d^2}$ and $\frac{bc-ad}{c^2-2d^2}$ are all in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Then, $xy^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. So, by the Subfield test $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$.

$\textbf{The question is how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(a)$ ?}$

Comment: $\sqrt2=-(a^2-2)$, so $\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\sqrt{2} = 2-a^2 \in \mathbb{Q}[a]$. Element in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is of the form $r_1 + r_2 \sqrt{2}$ for some $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{Q}$. Clearly $r_1+r_2\sqrt{2} = r_1 + r_2(2-a^2)\in\mathbb{Q}[a]$.